# How to send data from one Electron window to another with ipcRenderer using vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2, electron, vuex, vuex-modules

I have in one component this:

```
openNewWindow() {
    let child = new BrowserWindow({

        modal: true,
        show: false, 

    });
    child.loadURL('http://localhost:9080/#/call/' + this.chatEntityId + '?devices=' + JSON.stringify(data));
    child.on('close', function () { child = null; });

    child.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        child.show();
    });

    child.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
        console.log("done loading");
        ipcRenderer.send('chanel',  "data");
    });
}
```

And then in child window component:

```
mounted() {
    ipc.on('chanel', (event, message) => {
       console.log(message);
       console.log(event);
    });
}
```

I tried that `.on` in `created()` and `beforeCreate()` and with `this.$nextTick(), with`setTimeout` but nothing works.

I don't want to send some string data but object but as you can see not event simple string `"data"` works. I am out of ideas.

I can see that this only works in parent component for component where that emit came from if i do this:

1. send
2. listen in main process
3. send back to `event.sender`

So, question is how to pass any form of data from one window to another?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after long night, morning after solution.

1. In some vuejs componenet some action on button click for example

`ipcRenderer.send('chanel',  someData);`

2. In main process

   ```
   ipcMain.on('chanel', (event, arg) => {
      let child = new BrowserWindow()
      // other stuff here
      child.loadURL(arg.url)
      child.on('show', () => {
           console.log("done loading");
           child.webContents.send('data',  arg);
      });
   })
   ```
3. In vuejs component for other route `arg.url`

   ```
   mounted() {
       ipc.on('chanel', (event, message) => {
          console.log(message);
          console.log(event);
       });
   }
   ```